# Proof of Schlömilch's Generalization

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Schlömilch's Generalization theorem states:

> Let $u(n)$ be a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers such that the ratio of successive differences is bounded;there is a positive real number $N$, for which:
>
> $$\frac{\Delta u(n) }{\Delta u(n-1) }=\frac{u\left(n+1\right)-u\left(n\right)}{u\left(n\right)-u\left(n-1\right)}<N$$
>
> Then provided that  $f(n)$meets the same preconditions as in Cauchy's test, the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f\left(n\right)$ is equivalent to the convergence of:
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Delta u(n)f\left(u\left(n\right)\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(u\left(n+1\right)-u\left(n\right)\right)f\left(u\left(n\right)\right)$$
>
> the Cauchy condensation test emerges as a special case.

---

I searched for a proof of this theorem, but I could not find and it seems that the theorem is not famous that much, can anybody prove this and if it's possible then gives some examples?

Updated

---

Given a real non-negative decreasing sequence $\left\{a_{i}\right\}_{i\in \mathbb N^{+}}$, 
Define:

$$S_{n}:=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\;\;\;\;\;,\;\;\;\;\;\;u_i:=b^i\;\;\;\;\;,\;\;\;\;\;u_{-1}:=b^{-1}$$ Where $b \in \mathbb N_{\ge2}$ and $i\in \mathbb N$.

Clearly $u_i$ forms a sequence of strictly positive integers.

Since the terms $a_i$'s are non-negative hence:
$$S_{n+1}-S_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i=a_{n+1}\ge0$$

Which follows the sequence $\left\{S_{n}\right\}_{n \in \mathbb N^{+}}$ is monotone increasing,using this fact we see that

If $n<u_{k}$ then:

$$S_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\le\sum_{i=1}^{u_{k}}a_{i}\le a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+a_{4}+...+a_{u_{k}}+...+a_{u_{k+1}-1}$$$$=\left(u_{1}-u_{0}\right)a_{u_{0}}+\left(u_{2}-u_{1}\right)a_{u_{1}}+...+\left(u_{k+1}-u_{k}\right)a_{u_{k}}=\sum_{i=0}^{k}\left(u_{i+1}-u_{i}\right)a_{u_{i}}=\zeta_k$$

$$\iff$$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{S_{n}\le\zeta_k}\tag{I}$$

If $n>u_{k}$ then:

$$S_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\ge\sum_{i=1}^{u_{k}}a_{i}=a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+a_{4}+...+a_{u_{k-1}+1}+...+a_{u_{k}}$$$$\ge\left(u_{0}-u_{-1}\right)a_{u_{0}}+\left(u_{1}-u_{0}\right)a_{u_{1}}+...+\left(u_{k}-u_{k-1}\right)a_{u_{k}}=\sum_{i=0}^{k}\left(u_{i}-u_{i-1}\right)a_{u_{i}}=\frac{\zeta_k}{u_1}$$

$$\iff$$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{u_1S_{n}\ge\zeta_k}\tag{II}$$

(to be more precise $(\text{II})$ holds for any $M\ge u_{1}\ge 2$)

Combining $(\text{I})$ and $(\text{II})$ follows:

$S_{n}$ converges if and only if $\zeta_k$ converges and diverges if and only if $\zeta_k$ diverges.

Setting $u_i\mapsto2^i$ gives Cauchy condensation test .

---

The problem is that I have not used the facts that $u_i>u_{i-1}$ (I know this is true) and for a positive $M$ : $$\frac{u_{k+1}-u_{k}}{u_{k}-u_{k-1}}\le M$$

This is true if and only if $M\ge u_{1}\ge2$

(I again know that this is true).

So what is wrong with my proof? However I know that these two are true, but Since I've proved the theorem without using these two facts I'm not sure if the proof is right.

I think as long as $S_{n}\le\zeta_k\le MS_{n}$ holds for $M\ge u_{1}$ we are able to use the test (moreover since $u_i$ forms a strictly increasing sequence then if $M=u_{i}$ for natural $i\ge1$ then again we can use the test, that's what I think Wikipedia says).

---

Updated:

From page 122 of Theory And Application Of Infinite Series by Knopp,Konrad, I know that my definiton of $u_i$ is a special case, however I still don't know why do we need

Comment: The proof is found on page 121 of "Theory and Application of Infinite Series" by K. Knopp. I can write out the proof later this week if this question doesn't get a reply.

Comment: For a biography (in German) of Schlömilch that includes a list (on pp. 263-281) of about 360 items by Schlömilch from 1841 through 1900, see Moritz Benedikt Cantor (1829-1920), [*Nachruf an Oskar Schlömilch*](http://archiv.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/volltextserver/13393/1/schloemilch.pdf) [Obituary of Oskar Schlömilch], **Bibliotheca Mathematica** (3) 2 (1901), 260-281. From this you might be able to identify the actual original publication, and if so, you'll almost certainly be able to find it freely available on the internet. **(continued)**

Comment: Curiously, this very useful reference for Schlömilch's publications (published in probably the best known math history journal in the 1800s and early 1900s) is not mentioned in [The MacTutor History of Mathematics archive's biography of Schlömilch or in their list of references for Schlömilch](http://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Schlomilch.html). Similarly, it is not mentioned in the [Wikipedia page for Schlömilch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscar_Schl%C3%B6milch).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, thanks for the information.

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis, I tried to prove the theorem (and using your reference) , can you please look at that and explain my mistakes?

Comment: Bump: did anyone manage to track down the original paper in which this result by Schlömilch is proved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the complete proof if my memory serves me correctly, I always found the proof in Knopp a bit unpleasant to read so I tried to make it clearer.

We have by assumption that $f(n)$ is decreasing and $u_n$ is non-negative strictly increasing satisfying $\Delta u_n \leq C \Delta u_{n-1}$ for a $C > 0$, call the partial sums of the series $s_m = \sum_{n=0}^{m} f(n)$ and the partial sums of the condensed series by $t_m = \sum_{n=0}^{m} \Delta u_{n} f\left(u_{n}\right)$

Define $\displaystyle A=\sum_{n \geq 0: f(n)<f\left(u_{0}\right)} f(n) \quad$ when the index $m$ is such that $m < u_k$ we have the inequality

$$\begin{aligned}
s_{m} \leq s_{u_{k}} & =  A+\Big(f(u_{0})+f(u_{0}+1)+ \dots f\left(u_{1}-1\right)\Big)\\ & +\ldots+\mkern-1mu\Big(f\left(u_{k}\right)+f\left(u_{k}+1\right)+\ldots+f\left(u_{k+1}-1\right)\Big) \\
& \leq A+\mkern2mu\left(u_{1}-u_{0}\right) f\left(u_{0}\right)+\ldots+\left(u_{k+1}-u_{k}\right) f\left(u_{k}\right) \\[0.25cm] \text {since } f(n) \text { decreasing } \\{}\\
&=A+t_{k}
\end{aligned}$$

The first line is breaking up the sum of the first $u_k$ many terms by $A$ and whatever is left over, then we group up the terms in the large brackets and estimate each $f$ with the largest choice in the large bracket.

When the index $m$ is such that $m>u_{k}$
$$
\begin{aligned}
s_{m} \geq s_{u_{k}} & \geq\Big(f\left(u_{0}+1\right)+f\left(u_{0}+2\right)+\ldots+f\left(u_{1}\right)\Big)+\ldots+\Big(f\left(u_{k-1}+1\right)+\ldots+f\left(u_{k}\right)\Big) \\
& \geq\left(u_{1}-u_{0}\right) f\left(u_{1}\right)+\ldots+\left(u_{k}-u_{k-1}\right) f\left(u_{k}\right)\\
& = \sum_{j=1}^k\Delta u_{j-1}f(u_j)\\
& \geq \sum_{j=1}^k\frac{1}{C}\Delta u_{j}f(u_j)
\end{aligned}
$$

The first and second line use the same trick as before, but this time we estimate each $f$ with the lowest choice in the large brackets, and the final inequality uses the assumption on $u_n$.

The last inequality leads to
$$
C s_{m} \geq t_{k}-t_{0}
$$

So we have shown that $t_k$ and $s_k$ always bound one another above and below (we don't worry about the conditions $m > u_k$ and so on since we can make either one as big as we need in the infinite sum), thus the convergence and divergence of one are determined by the other.

The special case $u_n = 2^n = \Delta u_n\;, C=1$ is the Cauchy condensation test.

Comment: If anyone knows how to stop Latex from shunting the entire first inequality for no reason whatsoever I would be very appreciative.

Comment: First thank you for the proof, but did you read my question?

Comment: I think your $(I)$ is correct, the line starting with $(u_1 - u_0 )$ uses the fact that $u_i$ is increasing and would not be true otherwise. I think the mistake is in $(II)$, for a start $u_{-1}$ makes no sense and I am unsure if the first inequality is correct.

Comment: Good point, but let me explain why it's true, the mentioned inequality is true if $$a_{1}\ge\left(u_{0}-u_{-1}\right)a_{u_{0}}$$  is true, and notice that :
$$a_{1}\ge\left(u_{0}-u_{-1}\right)a_{u_{0}}$$

 $$\iff$$ 

$$a_{1}\ge\left(b^{0}-b^{-1}\right)a_{b^{0}}\tag{definiton of $u_i$}$$$$\iff$$$$a_{1}\ge\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)a_{1}$$$$\iff$$

Non-negatively of $a_i$ follows:


$$1\ge1-\frac{1}{b}$$


Which is true, since $b$ is strictly positive based on the definition of $u_i$.

Comment: Besides if you think a negative index is not regular, then you are right, that's why I defined that explicitly (moreover  "Theory and Application of Infinite Series" by K. Knopp also has used such negative index).

Comment: I see now, then I think your proof works fine thanks to the nice manipulations you can perform when $u_i$ is of the form $b^i$. This satisfies the assumption of the general proof with $C = b-1$ so the conclusion doesn't lead to any contradictions which is a good sign.

Comment: Now I understand that my $u_i$ is indeed a special case, but why in your proof do we need $u_i$ to be non-negative?what will happen if it's negative?also why this sequence should be a sequence of integers?maybe because it's an index?

Comment: Every time something like $s_{u_k}$ or $f(u_k)$ is written I am implicitly assuming that $u_k$ is a positive integer so it can be used as an index for the sequence $s_m$ or in the domain of $f(n)$. 

I probably should have included this as another assumption that $u_i$ is $\mathbb{N}$ valued, but I suppose the proof could be extended if we considered something like the integer part of $u_k$, so positive, increasing would then indeed suffice. Negative values would not work however, since a "$-1$th partial sum" would not make sense.

Comment: You are right, the only thing that I still don't get is that why $u_n$ should be strictly increasing?, I know that :$$C\left(u\left(n\right)-u\left(n-1\right)\right)\ge u\left(n+1\right)-u\left(n\right)$$$$\iff$$$$C\ge\frac{u\left(n+1\right)-u\left(n\right)}{\left(u\left(n\right)-u\left(n-1\right)\right)}$$ is true, if and only if $u_n$ is strictly increasing

Comment: But why do we even need to to convert $$C\left(u\left(n\right)-u\left(n-1\right)\right)\ge u\left(n+1\right)-u\left(n\right)$$ to $$C\ge\frac{u\left(n+1\right)-u\left(n\right)}{\left(u\left(n\right)-u\left(n-1\right)\right)}$$?this division just creates some limitation.

Comment: The strictly increasing assumption is again required for $u_k$ to be well defined as an index, and has nothing to do with the bound relating $\Delta u_k$, that is just used to bound things at in the final line in terms of $t_k$. Formally we are considering $(s_{u_m})_{m \geq 0}$ as a sub-sequence of  $(s_m)_{m \geq 0}$. Something like $a_1, a_2, a_4, a_8 ....$ or $a_p : p$ prime is a valid subsequence, but we can't have the index "go down" or repeat in a way like $a_0, a_1, a_1, a_0, a_2, a_3, a_4 ...$. So we impose strictly increasing to make $u_k$ a "legal" choice for a sub-sequence.