# Convergence of $\sum \frac{1}{n \ln(n) \ln(\ln(n)) ...}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know the series $$\sum_{N \leq n}{\frac{1}{n \ln(n) \ln(\ln(n)) ... (\ln^k)(n)}}$$ ($\ln^k$ is $\ln$ iterated $k$ times, not $\ln$ to the power of $k$) diverges for all constant $k$, as long as $N$ is big enough for it to be defined. However, I was wondering what happens if we extend that to infinity.

We can define a function
$$f(n) = \begin{cases} 
      1 & n\leq 1 \\
      n\cdot f(\ln(n)) & 1 < n
   \end{cases}
$$
Or equivalently $f(n) = n \ln(n) \ln(\ln(n)) ...$ as long as the $\ln$ is greater than $1$.

Does the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{1}{f(n)}}$$
converge? I thought about using the integral test and partitioning it based on the tetrations of $e$, but I can't think of any way to estimate
$$\int_{^{k}e}^{^{k+1}e}{\frac{dx}{x \ln(x) \ln(\ln(x)) ... (\ln^k)(x)}}$$

Comment: Note that, by the chain rule, $$\int_{{}^k e}^{{}^{k+1}e} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x (\log x)(\log^{\circ 2}x)\cdots(\log^{\circ k}x)}=\left[\log^{\circ(k+1)}x\right]_{{}^k e}^{{}^{k+1}e}=1.$$ (Alternatively, apply the substitution $u=1/x$ to find that the integral for $k+1$ is equal to the integral for $k$.)

Comment: @SangchulLee thanks! So the infinite integral diverges and so does the series?

Comment: You might look at Schlömilch's Test, a generalization of the Cauchy Condensation Test that is often useful in such situations when you are composing multiple functions. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3646387/207050), for instance.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764465/does-the-series-converge).